# MySQL Reporting - Order History

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have to create a MySQL Query for a report.

I have a table `history` which keeps record of status changes of a product's order. I have these statuses for an order's life cycle (the flow of an order): new, confirmed, processing, shipped, delivered, cancelled, returned. An order doesn't necessarily follow this status flow, for example: A new order can be cancelled immediately, or it can be cancelled while in processing. This makes the accurate reporting more complex.

Now I want to make a Supply Chain report of orders which were confirmed, processed, shipped and then delivered. But this report should exclude orders which were cancelled at any stage or returned.

Consider this example:

An order (id: 34) was placed by a customer. Initial status: New. Confirmed by an Agent, status set to Confirmed. Supply Chain manager verifies availability, status changes to Processing, then shipped and then delivered.

Another order (id: 55) comes, New, confirmed, processing but cancelled. `history` looks like:

```
id  order_id status
111 34       new
112 34       confirmed
113 55       new
114 55       confirmed
115 55       processing
116 34       processing
117 55       cancelled
118 34       shipped
119 34       delivered
```

How do I make a report query to get only those orders which were

1. Confirmed, Processed, shipped and delivered.
2. Confirmed, processed, cancelled.
3. confirmed, cancelled
4. and so on...

How can I write a query to get these kinds of reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for new order:select distinct(order_id) from history where status = new
for new processed:select distinct(order_id) from history where status = processed 
 and so on

for those order which are new, processed and delivered

select t1.order_id from history as t1, history as t2, history as t3 where t1.order_id=t2.order_id and t2.order_id=t3.order_id and t1.status=new and t2.status = processed and t3.status = delivered

like this go on for others

Comment: That's great. What if I also put time in `WHERE` clause. Like `t3.date_added > t2.date_added and t2.date_added > t1.date_added`. Meaning, an order was first new, then set to processes and then to delivered. This way I'll be able to sort status flow as well... Right?

Comment: yahh you can do that. and if the answer is helpful don't forget to accept it. Thanks.